# Subprocess popen interaction with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv to run a script that uses subprocess popen to run another program that requires the system wide python and original environment variables. How do I prevent virtualenv from affecting it?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a modified `PATH` for the subprocess with `env=`.

```
from subprocess import Popen
from os import environ
from os.path import join as path_join

myenv = environ.copy()
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in environ:
    myenv['PATH'] = ':'.join(
        [x for x in environ['PATH'].split(':')
            if x != path_join(environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], 'bin')])
Popen(['command', '--with', 'arguments'], env=myenv)
```

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` creates a copy of python executable and you can activate it to your current shell:

> This will change your $PATH so its first entry is the virtualenv’s
>   bin/ directory. (You have to use source because it changes your shell
>   environment in-place.) This is all it does; it’s purely a convenience.
>   If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the
>   virtualenv’s bin/ directory (e.g. path/to/ENV/bin/pip or
>   /path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py) there’s no need for activation.

So when I've activated python in a virtualenv for my project it's the one that will be used:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/Projects/papukurier/papukurier$ source ../venv/bin/activate
(venv) gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/Projects/papukurier/papukurier$ which python
/home/gonczor/Projects/papukurier/venv/bin/python
(venv) gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/Projects/papukurier/papukurier$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/gonczor/Projects/papukurier/venv/bin/python'
>>>
```

But at the same time you can give full path to execute any other python instance on your computer:

```
(venv) gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/Projects/papukurier/papukurier$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm actuaĺly launching a rails server with popen, and that server then uses python, causing errors because it expects python2. Will using the python in virtualenv without activating solve the problem?

Comment: I only activated it to give more clear example. When executing scripts directly in my IDE I just pass the path to the executable without activating. Have you given the correct path? Can you verify it in a similar way I've presented above?

Answer (score 0):

I believe subprocess doesn't care about you venv

```
subprocess.run('/path/to/system/python program.py', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```